# Sending mail with embedded image in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email, pony

I want to send a mail with an attached image and embed this image in html. As a source for  tag , What should I write and is there any missing header parts such a content_type ?

When I am doing real test, I send to a mail to my gmail account. I can see there is an attachment with name "unnamed" and I could not display image even when I download.

Gem: Pony

```
require 'pony'
Pony.override_options = { :via => :test }
Pony.mail(
    :to => 'foo@bar',
    :from => 'abc@abc.com',
    :subject => 'test123',
    :body =>   "<h1><strong>Dear X, check the newsletter ,<br></strong></h1> <img src='attached image' />",
    :attachments => {"happy_image.jpg" => File.read("happy_image.jpg")}
)
puts Mail::TestMailer.deliveries
```

output:

```
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2016 17:23:05 +0300

From: abc@abc.com

To: foo@bar

Message-ID: <5846c9ca183d6_5983c9fd899060@MW7BIQ12TKYHQC.mail>

Subject: test123

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

boundary="--==_mimepart_5846c9caf15a_5983c9fd8989e5";

charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit





----==_mimepart_5846c9caf15a_5983c9fd8989e5

Content-Type: text/plain;

charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



<h1><strong>Dear X, check the newsletter ,<br></strong></h1> <img src='' />

----==_mimepart_5846c9caf15a_5983c9fd8989e5

Content-Type: image/jpeg;

 filename=happy_image.jpg

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-Disposition: attachment;

filename=happy_image.jpg

Content-ID: <happy_image.jpg@MW7BIQ12TKYHQC>



/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQE

BQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/

2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQU

FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAHiAuMDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QA

HwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUF

BAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkK

FhcYGQ==



----==_mimepart_5846c9caf15a_5983c9fd8989e5--
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to BASE64 encode the image, and use the resulting string as the `src` of the `img` tag.

For example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWQAAAD8CAYAAAB..."/>
```

Also make sure that your content type is set as `text/html` instead of `text/plain`. Looking at the mail, it seems that it's set to the latter, hence why images don't render and tags render as text. Add the following to your arguments to use `text/html` content type:

`:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }`

Comment: Hi , I have already tried this method, but when I display mail , it shows pure string with img tag like "<img src="data:image/png;base64,iV2312_encoding_string"/>"

Comment: Ah. You need to set the content type to HTML in the header, else it'll handle it as text. Looking at your original question, it seems that the content type is currently set as `text/plain`. I've updated the question to add this.

Comment: As you said I added headers option, but the result is the same for me. Like this pure string ''<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/ASD.../> :(

Comment: GMail strips imgs with the data embedded.